# User input doesn't match with the data in the file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im currently a new student new to python. I have face some problem with my code. You can see the source code below here, this program with start with a prompt asking the user to input their user id. Then the program will match the user id that user input with the user id exist in the StudentIDs.txt but it seem like it is not working very well.

```
def login_menu():  
    while True:
        user_input_id = (input('Please enter your student ID: '))
        with open('StudentIDs.txt', 'r+') as student_ids:
            if user_input_id in student_ids.read():
                print('You have access to the system')
            else:
                print('Invalid ID, the ID is not in the database, please try again')
```

Here is the data in the StudentIDs.txt

```
1904983
1904984
1904985
```

When I input 1904983 I will get access to the system but when I input 190 or 1 or 9 I will also have access to the system, this made the program not logic at all. Can someone please explain to me what's wrong with my program or maybe give me a help?

Comment: Try `[line.strip() for lin in student_ids.readlines()]` instead of `student_ids.read()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
def login_menu():  
    user_input_id = (input('Please enter your student ID: '))
    with open('file.txt') as student_ids:
        ids = [line.strip("\n") for line in student_ids]
        if str(user_input_id) in ids:
            print('You have access to the system')
        else:
            print('Invalid ID, the ID is not in the database, please try again')

login_menu()
```

The trick is `[line.strip("\n") for line in student_ids]` where it splits all the lines by the "\n" (new line) and put them together in a array called ids.

Then:

```
if str(user_input_id) in ids:
```

it just checks if the you got the input in the array.

Note: Don't forget to convert to string!

Comment: Thanks a lot, using your code I am able to run the program logically now.

Answer (score 0):

Try using == instead of in 
i.e. Your code should look like:

```
if user_input_id == student_ids.read():
```

the difference between the 2 statements is that, when you use the **in** operator it will check if the user_input is present in the student_id or not (even if one of the values present will output True). On the other hand, **==** looks for an exact match between the values.

Comment: seem like == doesn't work. I just get Invalid ID in return. Maybe you have other suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: As Sayandit Dutta said, you also need to iterate through the file, so,Try [line.strip() for lin in student_ids.readlines()] instead of student_ids.read()

Answer (score 0):

```
if user_input_id in student_ids.read():
```

Here when you use "user_input_id in" it checks if the content in user_input_id is matching any part in student_ids. It is not comparing with the whole line, in your case whole user id. So, it will work if you read the file first and put all id in the list, loop through the list and compare using "==" or loop through each line in the file and compare using "==".

```
user_input_id = (input('Please enter your student ID: '))
with open('StudentIDs.txt') as fp:
    while True:
        line = fp.readline()
        if line:
            if user_input_id == line.strip():
                print('You have access to the system')
            else:
                print('Invalid ID, the ID is not in the database, please try again')
        else:
            break
```

Comment: May I know how do i loop through the file?